# Specialization of Scala methods to a specific tags

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

I have a generic map with values, some of which can be in turn lists of values.
I'm trying to process a given key and convert the results to the type expected by an outside caller, like this:

```
// A map with some values being other collections.
val map: Map[String, Any] = Map("foo" -> 1, "bar" -> Seq('a', 'b'. 'a'))

// A generic method with a "specialization" for collections (pseudocode)
def cast[T](key: String) = map.get(key).map(_.asInstanceOf[T])
def cast[C <: Iterable[T]](key: String) = map.get(key).map(list => list.to[C].map(_.asIntanceOf[T]))

// Expected usage
cast[Int]("foo")          // Should return 1:Int
cast[Set[Char]]("bar")    // Should return Set[Char]('a', 'b')
```

This is to show what I would like to do, but it does not work. The compiler error complains (correctly, about 2 possible matches). I've also tried to make this a single function with some sort of pattern match on the type to no avail.

I've been reading on @specialized, TypeTag, CanBuildFrom and other scala functionality, but I failed to find a simple way to put it all together. Separate examples I've found address different pieces and some ugly workarounds, but nothing that would simply allow an external user to call `cast` and get an exception is the cast was invalid. Some stuff is also old, I'm using Scala 2.10.5.

Comment: Why do you need the second cast method (for the iterable)?  The first one should be enough.

Comment: I think I'm failing to see a problem. `def cast(m: Map[String, Any], key: String) = m(key) match { case x: Int => x }` correctly returns integer and throws with a set. You might need classtags for determining the set type, but this one works with your example

Comment: that changes the header for `cast` and I don't want it to throw with a set, I want the set, casted correctly. Plus, calling `cast[Set[Char]]` does not automatically call the second overload even being more specific that the first.

Comment: @Archeg well, it is kinda pseudocode. The idea is that you would need to cast the outer type, and also cast the inner elements.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work but it has a some problems.

```
def cast[T](m: Map[String, Any], k: String):T = m(k) match {
  case x: T => x
}
```

With the right input you get the correct output.

```
scala> cast[Int](map,"foo")
res18: Int = 1

scala> cast[Set[Char]](map,"bar")
res19: Set[Char] = Set(a, b)
```

But it throws if the type is wrong for the key or if the map has no such key (of course).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is indeed something I'm doing as an alternative, but it matches on the type of the object retrieved, not on the type of the call. It is thus impossible for me to do a custom conversion like Seq to Set or other. I want to be able to run custom code depending on the type applied to the method (hence specialization).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via implicit parameters:

```
val map: Map[String, Any] = Map("foo" -> 1, "bar" -> Set('a', 'b'))

abstract class Casts[B] {def cast(a: Any): B}
implicit val doubleCast = new Casts[Double] {
  override def cast(a: Any): Double = a match {
    case x: Int => x.toDouble
  }
}

implicit val intCast = new Casts[Int] {
  override def cast(a: Any): Int = a match {
    case x: Int => x
    case x: Double => x.toInt
  }
}

implicit val seqCharCast = new Casts[Seq[Char]] {
  override def cast(a: Any): Seq[Char] = a match {
    case x: Set[Char] => x.toSeq
    case x: Seq[Char] => x
  }
}


def cast[T](key: String)(implicit p:Casts[T]) = p.cast(map(key))

println(cast[Double]("foo")) // <- 1.0
println(cast[Int]("foo"))     // <- 1
println(cast[Seq[Char]]("bar")) // <- ArrayBuffer(a, b) which is Seq(a, b)
```

But you still need to iterate over all type-to-type options, which is reasonable as `Set('a', 'b').asInstanceOf[Seq[Char]]` throws, and you cannot use a universal cast, so you need to handle such cases differently.

Still it sounds like an overkill, and you may need to review your approach from global perspective

Comment: Yeah. I would need to add one implicit for every type :-(